# Issues retrieving repeated child nodes using XPath using Java

Tags: java, xpath

I have the below structure where parent nodes are repeating nodes - lets say 5 nodes. Within these 5 parent nodes, I have 5 repeating child nodes with 5 attributes. I need to retrieve the values of attributes depending upon the value of the attribute.

Lets say one of the attribute values is `"Credit card"` for one of the rows and for the other 4 rows value of the attribute value is `"Debit card"`. When the value `== "Credit card"`, I need to take the values of the other attributes. I have tested that only one row exists for `attribute value == "Credit card"` and at least one row exists for the `attribute value == "Debit card"`

So basically I need to get a hold of the 5 child nodes for each instance of the parent.

I am able to retrieve the 5 instance of parent nodes with the right XPath, but I retrieve the child nodes using the `getchild()` method, but I get child nodes as 25 (in case if we have 5 parent nodes - 5 * 5) but instead of 5 nodes. Basically, I am unable to get a hold of child nodes (count 5) . Whatever way I use, I always retrieve all child nodes under all parent nodes, instead of a particular parent node.

```
<Parent1>
    <child1>"Attribute-1"=Value "Attribute-2"=Value2 "Attribute-3"="Value3" "Attribute-4"=Value2 "Attribute-5"=Value2</child1>
    <child2>"Attribute-1"=Value "Attribute-2"=Value2 "Attribute-3"="Value3" "Attribute-4"=Value2 "Attribute-5"=Value2</child2>
    <child3>"Attribute-1"=Value "Attribute-2"=Value2 "Attribute-3"="Value3" "Attribute-4"=Value2 "Attribute-5"=Value2</child3>
    <child4>"Attribute-1"=Value "Attribute-2"=Value2 "Attribute-3"="Value3" "Attribute-4"=Value2 "Attribute-5"=Value2</child4>
    <child5>"Attribute-1"=Value "Attribute-2"=Value2 "Attribute-3"="Value3" "Attribute-4"=Value2 "Attribute-5"=Value2</child5>
</Parent1>
<Parent2>
    <child1>
    <child2>
    <child3>
    <child4>
    <child5>
</Parent2>
<Parent2>
    <child1>
    <child2>
    <child3>
    <child4>
    <child5>
</Parent3>
<Parent4>
    <child1>
    <child2>
    <child3>
    <child4>
    <child5>
</Parent4>
<Parent5>
    <child1>
    <child2>
    <child3>
    <child4>
    <child5>
</Parent5>
```

Comment: Kindly suggest how can we handle xpath using java. I wish to avoid using xmlapth as I have already done 99% of my code using xpath . I wish to avoid to switching to xmlpath .I would be thankful for solution towards this issue.

Comment: XML structure incase its not posted incorrectly above:<Parent1>
 <child1>"Attribute-1"=Value "Attribute-2"=Value2 "Attribute-3"="Value3" "Attribute-4"=Value2 "Attribute-5"=Value2</child1>
 <child2>"Attribute-1"=Value "Attribute-2"=Value2 "Attribute-3"="Value3" "Attribute-4"=Value2 "Attribute-5"=Value2</child2>
 <child3>"Attribute-1"=Value "Attribute-2"=Value2 "Attribute-3"="Value3" "Attribute-4"=Value2 "Attribute-5"=Value2</child3>
 <child4>"Attribute-1"=Value "Attribute-2"=Value2 "Attribute-3"="Value3" "Attribute-4"=Value2 "Attribute-5"=Value2</child4>